# Exception User -Unhandled

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```css
[Area("Customer")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

```html
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
              
            });
```

I create as.pnet core mvc application I create customer area then I move home controller and home folder from controller and views to the controller and views inside Customer area then I put the route in startup file when I run the app an exception error displayed saying :Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException: 'An error occurred while creating the route with name 'areas' and template '{area:Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}'.'
what is the problem and how I can solve it ?

Comment: What is the purpose for `area:Customer`?

Answer (score 0):

For `area:Customer`, it means restrict the area follows `Customer` rule which is invalid. You could view [Route constraint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference) for valid constraint.

If you want the default area is `Customer`, you should change `:` to `=` like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areas",
    template: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
```